# Change start day of the week impala

Tags: sql, impala

I am trying to change the start day of the week, but not able to achieve
currently its Monday to sunday, it should be made sunday- saturday
I tried using this query on the below dataset `invoice date` and `invoice_week`

```
 SELECT invoice_date,
        weekofyear(invoice_date) as invoice_week,
        datesub(invoice_date,1),
        weekofyear(datesub(invoice_date,1)) as invoice_week1 
   from table
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of subtract the date by 1, you should add the date by 1:

```
select 
        invoice_date,
        weekofyear(invoice_date) as invoice_week,
        adddate(invoice_date,1),
        weekofyear(adddate(invoice_date,1)) as invoice_week1 
from(
        select cast('2018-01-07 16:00:00' as timestamp) invoice_date
)stg
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution which works. Given a date, here's the Date for the start of the week and end of the week if you want a Sunday - Saturday week, not a Monday - Sunday week as is default.

```
SET var:date=2019-01-06;
select  to_date(IF( dayofweek(cast('${var:date}' as timestamp)) = 1, cast('${var:date}' as timestamp), trunc(cast('${var:date}' as timestamp), 'd') - interval 1 day)) as startOfWeek, to_date(IF( dayofweek(cast('${var:date}' as timestamp)) = 1, (trunc(cast('${var:date}' as timestamp) + interval 1 day, 'd') + interval 5 day), (trunc(cast('${var:date}' as timestamp), 'd') + interval 5 day) )) as endOfWeek;
+-------------+------------+
| startofweek | endofweek  |
+-------------+------------+
| 2019-01-06  | 2019-01-12 |
+-------------+------------+
```